# If with false and 1 value in php

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code:

```
if($coupon->excluding_discounted){ 

   if(!$product->price_after_discount){
        // do something
  }

}
```

The code worked perfectly but I thought to convert this to one if ...

`dd($coupon->excluding_discounted,!$product->price_after_discount);`

```
1

false
```

How to check if the value of something is 1 and another element is false to do something ...?

**Update:**

my full code:

```
$products->map(function($product) use($coupon){

        if($coupon->excluding_discounted && !$product->price_after_discount){
                user()->cart()->updateExistingPivot($product, [
                    'coupon_id' => $coupon->id,
                ]);
        }

    });
```

the logic of code is if the product has discount and the excluding_discounted in coupon is true do the reset of code

I tried like this but it store the coupon_id even there is a discount on product! but with if inside if worked perfectly

Comment: You have `!$product->price_after_discount` in the former code and `$product->price_after_discount` in the latter (the `!` is missing.)

Comment: @GuyIncognito no I just forget the ! in if but I already wrote it in real test and didn't work!

Comment: Of course you did.

Answer (score 3):

You can join `if` statements together, like so:

```php
if ($coupon->excluding_discounted && !$product->price_after_discount) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: yeah I do this and the code not working like I need, and it's works with two if ?! that's why I ask this!!

Comment: More info at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: @akin You'll have to update your question with more information then, as the above `if` statement in my answer replicates the same functionality as yours does as separate `if`'s.

Comment: Updated pls check it again!

Comment: Your updated answers reflects something that fits your test criteria, so one can only assume that what you're testing doesn't match the criteria you're looking for. For example, are you looking at the correct product & have the correct coupon applied?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test strictly the value of a variable you can use the === operator :

```
if (1 === $coupon->excluding_discounted
    && false === $product->price_after_discount
) {
    // do something here
}
```